# undefined method `find_each' for Thor::Group:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thor

I have written a Thor task that's supposed to iterate through all Users leveraging `find_each`. But I get this error message:
**undefined method `find_each` for Thor::Group:Class`**

Why isn't find_each available here? Running `User.find_each { |u| puts u.name }` in rails console works.

```
class CloudImages < Thor
  require "./config/environment.rb"

  desc "save_user_avatar_urls", "Save existing AWS user avatars"
  def save_user_avatar_urls
    User.find_each do |user|
      next if user.avatar_url.blank?

      path      = URI(user.avatar_url).path
      image_url = $DOMAIN + path

      user.update_attribute(:aws_avatar_url, image_url)
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Try `::User.find_each do |user|`

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Post it as an answer so that I can accept it as correct. ;-)

Comment: Why do we have to use the base namespace here, and is there anyway to configure Thor to not need that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `User` to `::User`

```
class CloudImages < Thor
  require "./config/environment.rb"

  desc "save_user_avatar_urls", "Save existing AWS user avatars"
  def save_user_avatar_urls
    ::User.find_each do |user|
      next if user.avatar_url.blank?

      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why do we have to use the base namespace here, and is there anyway to configure Thor to not need that?